# What about this suggested edit deviates from the post?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

This [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6147077) was rejected earlier.

I do realize that my change in title may have been a stretch, and I added in a few words that weren't there, but my main focus was to format the table design a little better. Can anyone explain what about this was so far off, or if it was one of the things I've already mentioned?

Also - what is good practice at this point? Should I go back and just try to reformat the table, and leave the rest of the question as-is?

Comment: The only thing wrong with your edit-suggestion is the summary. While imo the table post-edit looks slightly better, the title-edit is actually more important.

Comment: @deduplicator Do you think the title change was too extreme? My thought process was to word it in a way that was more specific to the SQL problem at hand, not the project itself.

Comment: No, the title-change was certainly not too extreme. Completely replacing the title is not uncommon.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to change the table formatting. The title edit is OK.

Comment: How long must you have taken to format that whole table, and then have your edit rejected?

Comment: @Majora320 I don't remember, but I doubt it was that bad, I got pretty good with cut and paste. ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was nothing per se wrong with your edit. In fact, it was even a good edit.

The problem was with your summary. You only mentioned fixing the table format.

Most editors, if they see big changes like that, without a clear description of why they improve the post, will reject it as being too drastic a change.

Next time, if you want to do that, mention all of the changes you make in the description.